# Pandas warning SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I can't seem to understand why I am getting a warning from my pandas code below:
I am trying to convert the column 'Sex' in the titanic.csv dataset to numeric using the code below:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
label_encoding = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
titanic_df['Sex'] =label_encoding.fit_transform(titanic_df['Sex'].astype(str))
titanic_df.head()
```

I get this warning:

```
<ipython-input-41-45071618b7c1>:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  titanic_df['Sex'] =label_encoding.fit_transform(titanic_df['Sex'].astype(str))
```

How do I format the code to avoid getting errors?

Comment: How is created `titanic_df` ?

Comment: like this: 

`titanic_df =pd.read_csv('datasets/train.csv')`

Comment: super, then later was no filtration?

Comment: I've seen the related post and read it but can't seem to get an answer to the question

Comment: I've also done some data cleaning:
`titanic_df.drop(['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'], 'columns', inplace=True)`

Comment: Try `titanic_df.loc[:, 'Sex']=...` instead of `titanic_df['Sex']=...`.

Comment: Use `titanic_df = titanic_df.drop(['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'], 'columns').copy()`

Comment: I used these two:
`titanic_df[titanic_df.isnull().any(axis=1)].count()`
`titanic_df=titanic_df.dropna()`

Should I replace with your code above?

Comment: Like dupe say if some filtration like `drop` is necessary add `.copy()`